# Rename PDF files with VBA

Tags: vba, pdf

I am trying to rename some pdf files with this kind of name: "2020-01-24-GOOGLE.NY-JPM-XXXXXXXXX.pdf"
into: "2020 01 24 - GOOGLE - JPM - 30p.pdf" with 30p meaning 30 pages (the number of pages in the pdf file).

The structure of the name is always the same, only the letters / numbers change.

I have already prepared some code (that you can find below), yet I am struggling with two things:

1. How can I "extract" the Broker name, (here JPM)
2. How can I get the number of pages in the pdf ? I have seen some solutions on the forum requiring Adobe Pro, yet I do not have access to it

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem ?

Here is the code:

```
Sub FetchName()
Dim nameArray() As Variant
Dim renameArray() As Variant
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim r As Integer
Dim Year As String
Dim Month As String
Dim Day As String
Dim Company As String
Dim Broker As String
Dim NPage As String
Dim numElements As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim AcroDoc As Object
Dim StartNum As Integer
Dim numCar As Integer

'get two inputs
myPath = Worksheets("Cover").Cells(3, 4)
Company = Worksheets("Cover").Cells(3, 2)

'get names in an array
myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.pdf")
r = 1
Do While myFile <> ""
ReDim Preserve nameArray(r)
nameArray(UBound(nameArray)) = myFile
   
r = r + 1
myFile = Dir
Loop

numElements = UBound(nameArray) - LBound(nameArray) + 1

'prepare array with new names
s = 1
For s = 1 To numElements

    Year = Left(nameArray(s), 4)
    Month = Mid(nameArray(s), 6, 2)
    Day = Mid(nameArray(s), 9, 2)
    
    StartNum = InStr(1, Replace(nameArray(s), "-", "~", 4), "~")
    
    numCar = InStr(1, Replace(nameArray(s), "-", "~", 5), "~") - InStr(1, Replace(nameArray(s), "-", "~", 4), "~") + 1
    Broker = Mid(nameArray(s), StartNum, numCar)

    'numpage

    'ReDim Preserve renameArray(r)
    'renameArray(UBound(renameArray)+1) = Year & " " & Month & " " & Day & " - " & Company & " - " & Broker & " - " & NPage & "p"
   
s = s + 1
Next s

'rename files with renameArray
t = 1
     For t = 1 To numElements
     Name myPath & nameArray(1) As myPath & renameArray(1)
     t = t + 1
Next t
End Sub


enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Broker name, you can use `InStrRev` to search for the position of the last and second last dashes:

```vb
namePDF = "2020-01-24-GOOGLE.NY-JPM-XXXXXXXXX.pdf"
lastDashAt = InStrRev(namePDF, "-")
secondLastDashAt = InStrRev(namePDF, "-", lastDashAt - 1)
Broker = Mid(namePDF, secondLastDashAt + 1, lastDashAt - secondLastDashAt - 1)
```